# Why is the entire page rerendered with reach router?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, reach-router

Only the login component should be rendered if the path is /login. It does work but now if the path is updated through Tabs component from /posts/1 to /posts/2 the entire page is re-rendered.

I actually want the login component to be displayed alone. Everything else should stay the same. I tried it like this:

```
import React from "react";
import Tabs from "./components/Tabs";
import { Router } from "@reach/router";
import SignIn from "./components/SignIn";
import AppBar from "./components/AppBar";

export default function Screen() {
    const Home = () => (
        <React.Fragment>
            <AppBar />
            <Tabs />
        </React.Fragment>
    );

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Router>
                <SignIn path="login" />
                <Home path="/*" />
            </Router>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to put the slash(/) for your login page.

```
 <SignIn path="/login" />
```

Comment: That is not the problem.